# How to identify software is used to create point and figure chart?

Tags: charts

I  am trying to learn on how to create charts on website for Point and figure charts. I am looking for any help with the clues on how to generate point and figure charts like:
https://chartink.com/pointfigure/nifty.html

[Point and Figure Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdmgm.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are various online javascript libraries, but I would suggest to use [D3.js](https://d3js.org/), examples [here](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery).